# how to compile the CCI (Common Compiler Infrastructure) AST libraries?

Tags: compiler-construction

Has anyone in the audience managed to do this?

I Downloaded the source code, project files, etc from codeplex; and it didnt even begin to compile under VS-2008. the .sln files are not compatible with VS-2008, but that was not a problem because the .proj files are still compatible.

So i manually reconstructed the .sln; but when i tried to build it, VS could not locate a single type name or assembly reference. A quick glance at the solution explorer revealed why: every assembly is cyclically dependent on all the others, which is normally not allowed on .net.

By all accounts, this should be impossible to build. Why then, is it even out there?? Could someone please tell me whats' going on with this thing?

thx,
anna

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate what you did, but when I look at my solution explorer (VS 2010), I see no cyclic dependencies.

A comment on the getting started page states that they had to upgrade to 2010 to get it to work, despite it saying that it is a solution for Visual Studio 2008.

Maybe the developers are lax, maybe its an outdated project. It's out there now because it worked before, and might now with 2010. Developers disappearing isn't all that unheard of in the FOSS world, so don't fret. Just update, or move on. It's really all that you can do.

Comment: Thx. Do you know if theres anything similar that doesnt have those problems? From what i hear, CCI may indeed be outdated; the replacement is called "phoenix" but thats all i know.

Comment: Try using phoenix, I'm personally a Linux person, and I opened VS for the first time to test this question out haha. Remember, one of the best skills to have as a programmer is being able to problem solve.

Comment: Well, I don't know of anything, and if both have been taking down without developers forking them, maybe they weren't so good in the first place eh? Maybe there are better ways to do what you want, how about asking for implementation help around here.

Although, I could be wrong. By no means did I conduct an exhaustive search of the internet to find a CCI replacement, but I didn't find anything in my searches.